# PHP MSQL Cannot authenticate to Mysql Database

Tags: mysql

I am buing VPN Website Using Smarty plugins

Here's my sql config

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "pass";
$DB_name = "db";

$mysqli = new MySQLi($DB_host,$DB_user,$DB_pass,$DB_name);
if($mysqli->connect_error){
   die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

I have setup new WHM and install Cloudlinux MySQL Governor, i seems issue on mysql when i have login to my vpn panel doesnt authenticate vpn accounts

I am requesting how fixed issue on my WHM Mysql server

Here's link https://xtreamvpn.xyz/login

Comment: Do you get an Error message?

Comment: No mate, when i'm pressing login keep stuck on loading screen

Comment: I'm not really sure if issue was on mysql cnf file